# What's the best way to get all Perl's builtin-functions as a list?

Tags: perl, function, built-in

I'm trying to update a xml-file for syntax-highlighting and therefor I was wondering what's the simplest way to get a list of all Perl built-in-functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is quick implementation of cnicutar's idea:

```
use Pod::Find qw(pod_where);

my $perlfunc_path = pod_where({ -inc => 1 }, 'perlfunc');

open my $in, "<", $perlfunc_path or die "$perlfunc_path: $!";
while(<$in>) {
    last if /=head2 Alphabetical/;
}

while(<$in>) {
    print "$1\n" if /=item (.{2,})/;
}
```

Gives you list including parameters like this:

```
-X FILEHANDLE
-X EXPR
-X DIRHANDLE
-X
abs VALUE
abs
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at the *toke.c* file in the `perl` source:

```
  $ perl -nE 'next unless /case KEY_(\S+):/; say $1' toke.c | sort | uniq
```

You'll find many of the things that won't show up in *perlfunc*. However, that depends on how you want to segment that various things that you want to color.

You could also look at [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PPI), a static Perl parser, or the existing Perl syntax highlighters.

Answer (score 3):

I would parse `perldoc perlfunc` (the part "Perl Functions by Category").

Comment: rather parse pod/perlfunc.pod as a more regular format (and has parsers like Pod::Simple that you can apply to the task)

Comment: Many of the things you'll need to find aren't in perlfunc.

Comment: @brian d foy He asked for `Perl built-in-functions`. What built-in functions aren't there ?

Comment: Are you sure he only needs built-in functions for syntax highlighting? Answering the literal question often misses the actual need.

Comment: @brian d foy I only answer what is asked. Guessing what's in the minds of stackoverflow users is beyond my abilities.

Comment: So, you don't have the ability to think what might go into a syntax highlighter? I think you just didn't take the time to consider it, shot off a one sentence answer based on something you've never done before, then defended based on ego rather than technical merit. You could always ask clarifying questions, but if you're not up to it, your role hear might be a reader rather than an answerer.

Comment: @brian d foy So the fact that the reader accepted that answer also doesn't mean anything to you. Again I say, don't guess. Also, I don't see where you asked your clarifying question "Do you perchance need all builtins?"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue just now, and

```
egrep '^=item' /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pod/perlfunc.pod | perl -anle '$F[1]=~s/\W//g; print $F[1]' | sort | uniq
```

worked for me (but, be warned, it's not perfect)